# Moving questions between sites

Tags: sffaq

How to move question between serverfault and stackoverflow?

Is it possible (maybe I don't have enough rep. to see this option)?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://serverfault.com/questions/8324/how-does-serverfault-work-the-community-faq)

Answer (score 12):

While Jeff [has said](http://serverfault.uservoice.com/pages/17382-general/suggestions/178800-show-related-items-on-stackoverflow) that this feature will be coming, there are some complicating factors. Primarily, since this site is running of a separate database with separate users, it might be difficult for the poster to retain ownership of the question. Will an account be automatically created here for the user when a question is moved? How is ownership determined, by OpenIDs? There are already some [problems](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/googles-openids-are-unique-per-domain/) with that approach.

I [had hoped](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/podcast-49/#comment-19786) that this site would use the same DB as Stack Overflow, as it would make things like moving questions between sites simple, but I guess Jeff felt differently.

**edit:** It's [now possible](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/) to migrate between all four sites (with the exception of migrating off Meta). Ownership is maintained through OpenIDs, and the Google OpenID problem is handled through account association.

Comment: This operation will most likely be constrained to moderators or question owners.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible at the mo.  I'm sure the team have considered it

One interesting problem I could see for the less frequent / drive-by users... it might not be obvious to them that their question had moved site... they might not be able to find it again?

Comment: I would guess if such a thing were implemented they would have a version of [closed], perhaps called [moved] so that a question placeholder could be found with a link to the moved version on the other site. Now that I've said it, perhaps that's too much complication.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

One of my questions did get moved, but as indicated my ownership of the question was removed and in fact my login on this site is busted.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators can currently move questions between sites from our menu.  Which you'll see in a moment when I move this question over the the meta site.

Comment: Look at the dates.

Comment: Well, the question is still correct and he is just answering :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming only mods can do this.